# Word 2013 displaying link as { HYPERLINK "http://domain.com/" }

Tags: microsoft-word, microsoft-office

I must have somehow triggered a setting in Microsoft Office Word 2013 Service Pack 1, where hyperlinks are displayed per the following screenshot:

[image: HYPERLINK]

Any thoughts on how to revert this back to rendering hyperlinks "normally" (clickable, blue, underlined text)?

Answer (score 1):

It looks like this is the "Field Codes" setting in Word. <kbd>ALT</kbd> + <kbd>F9</kbd> toggles the setting on and off. More information is available at the following URL:

http://blogs.technet.com/b/ryan_christiansen/archive/2008/04/28/text-in-brackets-is-displayed-in-a-microsoft-office-word-document-instead-of-an-image-hyperlink-embedded-object-or-some-other-content.aspx